# C# - query large number of AD users / a device attached to the system is no longer functioning

Tags: c#, directorysearcher

I am retrieving a handful of LDAP (Active Directory) properties for about 10,000 users. I know that AD queries aren't the fastest in the world but at the 19 minute mark (almost exactly) the program stops processing and about 15 minutes after that I get the error

> A device attached to the system is no longer functioning

on the `DirectorySearcher.FindOne()` method.

I don't think I'm doing anything weird in the code but I'm wondering if I need to re-write this to a `FindAll()` and then parse though that list.

```
searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + u.LogonName + ")";

string[] properties = new string[]
         {
                "givenName",
                "sn",
                "displayName",
                "mail",
                "physicalDeliveryOfficeName",
                "division",
                "grpDivision"
         };

searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);

SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
```

It doesn't stop on the same user every time and on the user it does stop on I've checked their attributes for anything that stands out and can't find anything out of the ordinary.

As you can imagine it gets quite tedious debugging in 35 minute increments so I'm hoping someone has seen this before or know about some hidden Active Directory connection time limit.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the actual query? This looks like it's just looking for one user by name, which (assuming your domain controller is not literally a potato) should not take 19 minutes.

Comment: What happens if you tell it to grab a copy of all users from Ad in one go, rather than one at a time?

Comment: I actually have a List<T> of ~10,000 users from an AD group and I'm iterating though one-at-a-time so I can populate the AD properties of each user. We have several DCs and it picks a different one each time but they are definitely not under-powered machines.

I'm thinking about just doing a FindAll on all user objects but I think I'll have the same problem because the DirectorySearcher doesn't actually give you all of the properties until the code is actually trying to use it. It's like a big yield return

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095510/creating-a-user-in-active-directory-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-func?rq=1 suggests something might be going on with samaccountname length (though in that question, the error occurred during a save and not a search...).

Answer (score 0):

Let's get your results in the biggest chunks we can.  Getting results one-at-a-time is very slow.  Unless you have tweaked your DC's settings, you can't get all 10,000 members at once; the default settings are to return a max of 1000 results at a time.  So we'll do 26 queries, one for each letter a sAMAccountName might start with, using the * operator.

```
public static IEnumerable<SearchResult> DirectMembers(string nameOfMyBigGroup)
{
    var namePrefixes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Select(c=>c.ToString());
    foreach(var namePrefix in namePrefixes) 
    {
        searcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + namePrefix + "*)(memberOf=" + nameOfMyBigGroup + "))";

        string[] properties = new string[]
            {
                "givenName",
                "sn",
                "displayName",
                "mail",
                "physicalDeliveryOfficeName",
                "division",
                "grpDivision"
            };

        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);

        var results = searcher.FindAll();
        foreach (var result in results) yield return result;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This assumes that your domain is set up such that sAMAccountName is case-insensitive, and that your users all have names whose first letters are drawn from the English alphabet.  If these assumptions are not met, you'd want to do a more robust solution involving paging.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this recently, where a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException` was thrown when attempting to query AD via `DirectorySearcher.FindAll` with the error message:

> A device attached to the system is not functioning

When this happens, you can catch that specific exception type (`DirectoryServicesCOMException`) and check the `ExtendedErrorMessage` property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryservicescomexception.extendederrormessage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#system-directoryservices-directoryservicescomexception-extendederrormessage) for additional info.

For example: In our case the `ExtendedErrorMessage` returned "00000008: SysErr: DSID-03021BAA, problem 12 (Not enough space), data 0" (where the 8 characters after "DSID-" are pointers to the file and line number in the AD source code so is something that might be helpful to Microsoft support but not in general for normal troubleshooting, but the rest of the message is helpful). This indicated there was some issue going on with one of our domain controllers (either out of disk space, or running out of RAM while executing the LDAP query). Our infrastructure team was able to find an unresponsive DC, reboot it, and then the error went away.

The main point is that the generic error message "A device attached to the system is not functioning" can be caused by different things, so check `DirectoryServicesCOMException.ExtendedErrorMessage` for more info.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't have a solid root cause - the problem has gone away. I haven't changed my code but when I tried it from home (on a VPN connection) the program successfully completes. It now takes 110 minutes due to the slower connection but it doesn't error out anymore.

Obviously it was something stemming from the server so I'm thinking I hit one of two possibilities.

1. I was bombarding the DC while on the LAN and it couldn't keep up.
2. The after-hours load on the DC is much lighter and allowing more resources to be allocated to my queries.

Comment: Did I violate some code of conduct for the down votes? I figured I'd post an answer so people don't waste time on it.

Comment: I think you may have been downvoted for giving an answer that didn't fully resolve the issue.  While it's good that things are working on your end, this answer may not be very helpful to future SO users who have this (or related) problem and find this question.