# Editing a user in Active Directory: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: c#

I'm trying to edit a user in active directory. Everything works fine and i can commit the users data except for department. When adding department I get this error:

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007001F): A device attached to the system is not functioning.

Comment: I think this would be better suited on Server Fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in my C# code. I mistakenly changed another attribut that was write protected.

Comment: full sample in C# ? ***sAMAccountName maxlength*** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095510/creating-a-user-in-active-directory-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-func